# A first chance exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, winforms

I have just developed 9 separate C#/Winforms applications.  Rather than having users install all 9 applications, I'd like to make one application which calls the necessary program with a button click.

I have made this program (Super-Program - to be created in Visual Studio) which is simply a field with 9 different buttons.

In the solution of the Super-Program, for each sub program, I have added the `subForm.cs`, `subForm.Designer.cs`, and `subProgram.cs` files.
I also generate the code necessary to run each program as a Form.

Everything works fine, but for each of my programs, when I click the appropriate button to run said program, I get an error message:`"A first chance exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll,` and it seems like it's missing the background image based on this line of the `Form.Designer.cs` file being highlighted by the Debugger:

```
this.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")));
```

However, if I double click the Form.resx file in the solution, It shows the appropriate Image in `$this.BackgroundImage.`  Does anyone know what's happening??

Thanks in advance!

Wyatt